# OP undid an edit to the question title

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

I attempted to edit the title of this question to make it more specific to the problem being asked.

[gcc compiles what it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388661/gcc-compiles-what-it-shouldnt)

See: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75388661/3

The OP changed the title back. So I added a comment to describe the purpose of my edit.

I am pretty sure I did not behave improperly. But, I decided I should humbly ask if there is anything I should have done differently to increase my chances of having the edit accepted.

Comment: You didn’t do anything wrong, dont waste your time on poor questions and users who don’t care :)

Comment: The post author has the right to refuse your editing help.  In this particular case, however, I think the edit is slightly off, or at least I can understand why the OP might think so.  The apparent premise of the question is that the issue is at the `sprintf()` calls, and your edit pointed to the variable initialization instead.  You are right that that's where the key action occurs, but the OP probably would not have asked the question in the form they did if they recognized that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for that. I have added additional context to my answer to point out the undefined behavior of the addition operation, for which there is no requirement for a diagnostic.

Comment: @Larnu in my experience, users with thousands of reputation points and a decade+ of posting history are frequently at least as protective of their precious question and title text, if not more.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "but the OP probably would not have asked the question in the form they did if they recognized that." - yes, but questions don't exist to help OP; they exist to become part of a Q&A library. Titles should look the way that will be useful for attracting the attention of others who have the same problem (and duplicate closers who recognize that someone's problem is common).

Comment: That's a bit strong, @KarlKnechtel.  Questions *do* exist to help the OP.  That's part of the *quid pro quo*, and so is the amount of control of their own questions that we afford to authors.  Questions *also* exist to help others and to become part of a QA library, which is on the other side.  In any case, my previous comment is primarily about the OP's perception of the edit, not about what the most appropriate title for the question would be.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I've had to reject bad approved edits that got through the review queue. It's hard to write a general rule; but most of the time we prefer the author have the say.

Answer (score -11):

I've had to deal with this myself on one of my extraordinarily popular [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum). People keep editing the title to something *other* than what I wrote. What I wrote, I wrote very carefully, and I've undone a lot of attempts to change it.

It's his title; let it say whatever he wants. You can *suggest* improvements. But in the end if he rejects it: that's his decision.

You may disagree with that, and that's fine: you're allowed to disagree.

---

His best course of action is to do what I do:

- some mod comes in dictating how it's going to be
- I create a reminder for a 12 months from now
- and then put it back

It's the way to avoid the pissing match with the person who can't leave things alone.

Comment: The example you've given doesn't really fit here. I agree that "How to enumerate an enum?", "How do I enumerate an enum?", etc are all pretty much the same and is a question of style, and it's reasonable to allow the OP to decide which phrasing they prefer. However, "gcc compiles what it shouldn't" could apply to literally tens of thousands of questions and is an objectively less useful title than "Why does gcc not detect overflow on variable initialization?". OPs don't get to make the title of a question worse just because it's their title. That's not how the site works.

Comment: "avoid the pissing match" -- on the contrary. Planning your moves a year ahead, you seem to have turned into some strange, almost obsessive, long-term struggle... for what end? The purity of the title of a question you donated to the community the moment you posted it?

Comment: @DanMašek Why edit titles back to what I originally wrote? To make Stackoverflow better.

Comment: My commentary: struggle over something not worth struggling over.